# Classes not generated from tables in Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After the creation of the model from my database, my model context has references to the tables in the database but classes for those tables are not generated. Is this supposed to be like that? Do I now need to manually create classes for each of those tables?

Comment: The classes should be brought down; within the `model.edmx > model.tt` area in Solution Explorer...

Comment: @ne1410s im not sure i understand. what do you mean brought down?

Comment: Sorry - I mean automatically provided for you.  When you single-click on the .edmx file in visual studio (if that's your IDE?), do you see a table diagram?

Comment: That is correct...the model is created and all tables are included but I dont know where to find classes for those tables. Is this normal? Should I manually create the classes?

Comment: If you expand the .edmx file, you should see a .tt file within it.  If you then expand that, you should see the classes

Comment: Right I see that...now only one class was generated - it is db.context.cs. Inside this file is references to classes that have the same names as the names in the database...but these classes have not been autogenerated. Does this mean I have to create classes manually for each of the tables?

Comment: On the edmx table diagram, try right-clicking and selecting `Update Model from Database`, then making sure to add any tables that you wish to import.  That's about all I know of EF - so hope that helps

Comment: Just because you're using [tag:entity-framework] and ASP.NET doesn't mean that you're using [tag:asp-classic].  Please learn the difference and tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my configuration files. I migrated my new code to a new project and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Hey are you using Visual Studio?
If you have alreay done an update on edmx that means all your changes have come to your conext.Right click the TT files and click on "Run custom tool" option.This should auto generate the files you need (assuming you using Visual studio).

Comment: Can only see "Run custom tool" on the edmx file not on the tt files. VS2022 17.6.5

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me for a simple reason. Which is when the table I created in the database doesn't have a primary key.